# Google App Engine (Java) + Spring managed PersistenceManager

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

I've got kinda problem with JDO persistence of a list of just retrieved objects.

What I want to do is to:

- Fetch list of "Orders"
- Modify one property "status"
- Make bulk update of "Orders"

What I've got so far is **"Object with id ... is managed by a different Object Manager"**.
But wait, I haven't faced such a problem without Spring!

I tried to debug it like this:

```
List<Orderr> orders = orderDao.findByIdAll(ordersKeys);
for(Orderr o : orders) {
    System.out.println(JDOHelper.getPersistenceManager(o).hashCode());
    //hashcode is 1524670
    o.setSomething(somevalue);
}
orderDao.makePresistentAll(orders); //hashcode inside is 31778523
```

makePersistentAll does nothing but:

```
try {
    System.out.println(getPersistenceManager().hashCode());
    getPersistenceManager().makePersistentAll(entities);
} finally {
    getPersistenceManager().close();
}
```

All my DAOs extend **JdoDaoSupport**. Pmf is injected and managed by spring.

Finally, here is the question: Why is the persistence manager closed after findByIdAll? Or why do I get new persistence manager instance? My findByIdAll method doesn't call close on persistence manager, of course.

*Of course if I call makePersistent for each "order" it works well. But it breaks layering of business and database logic...*

**UPD**
Just found out that all calls to makePersistentAll aren't working at all after migration to spring managed PersistenceManager. Before spring I used plain old PMF.get() helper and everything was shiny!

Answer (score 1):

If your app remains live in response to a HTTP request for longer than 30 seconds, it will be killed. Part of the mode of operation of GAE is that your apps are not long-lived. At all.

Though you wouldn't do this on a site of your own, you'll have to get used to having only short-term access to your DB session manager. A lot of time is sometimes needed to re-open it for every transaction, but that's how GAE makes the process scalable. If you really have a lot of traffic, it can run your application in parallel on several servers.

Comment: Although I'm developing GAE app, it's not specific to it. I've got same thing on localhost SDK (nothing but Jetty). And I thought that, as you say, "DB session manager" is PersistenceManagerFactory but not PersistenceManager. I can get my old PersistenceManager from each object, but it's not the way I should do it. It means that it's not closed at all, but removed by spring from dao, I guess.

Comment: Hmm. Then I think we've gone beyond my ability to help you. I used some Spring in a GAE app, but our relationship was not a happy one. Sorry, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of magic. Everytime I ask here a question I know the answer to my question within 24 hours after post.

Of course, factory by its meaning should always create a new pm instance. Now I save reference to my old pm (like I did before spring jdo daos) and everyting is ok.